# Shuffling a deck of cards with images

Tags: c#, winforms, shuffle, outofrangeexception

Im trying to randomize a list and then put it out to an picturebox. When i do this i get the error message "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less then the size of the collection"

Here is the code for random:

```
public class Dealer
{
    public static Random rand = new Random();
    public static List<Kort> KortenÄrBlandade = new List<Kort>();
    public void Shuffle()
    {
        List<Kort> KortenÄrBlandade = new List<Kort>(deckOfCards.OrderBy(_ => rand.Next(0, deckOfCards.Count)));
    }
}
```

And here is the code for calling the method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Spelare.Dealer deal = new Spelare.Dealer();
    deal.Shuffle();
    pictureBox1.Image = Spelare.Dealer.KortenÄrBlandade[2].img;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that initialise deckOfCards ?

Comment: Please don't post your answer in the question.  Answers should be posted as answers.

Comment: Doesn't Card32.dll that is provided with windows contain all these shuffle and draw features ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using *Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

It could be something like that:

```
public class Dealer {

  // Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm with explicit generator
  private static void CoreShuffle(IList<Kort> list, Random generator) {
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, list))
      throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, generator))
      throw new ArgumentNullException("generator");

    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      int index = generator.Next(i + 1);

      Kurt h = list[index];
      list[index] = list[i];
      list[i] = h;
    }  
  }

  public static Random rand = new Random(); // <- Be careful: Random is not thread safe; readonly is also a good addition here

  // Return new shuffled list based on deckOfCards      
  public List<Kort> ShuffledList() {
    List<Kort> result = new List<Kort>(deckOfCards); // <- Check this line in your code
    CoreShuffle(result, rand);

    return result;   
  }
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using an existing shuffle too. Shuffling is trickier than it looks, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You re-created the exact same bug that the OP is suffering from.

Comment: Sorry. Im a beginner in C# and i think i might be over my head with this. Im just trying to create a blackjack game. I tried using the code you provided but i have no idea how to use it really. I tried using picturebox1.image = "what should i put here" and how do i call for the shuffle method ?

Comment: You comment on your `Random()` call that it is not threadsafe. You should also comment that it isn't random enough for proper deck shuffling.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Shuffle` method doesn't shuffle the static list, but creates (and forgets) a variable that is local to the method.
So your `Spelare.Dealer.KortenÄrBlandade` is never set to any real cardlist. Which means that index 2 doesn't exist, which is what the error message says.

A side remark: your mix of a static cardlist + instance Shuffle method is a bit strange ...

Comment: Hans Kesting is pointing you straight(flush) to the core of the bug.. The Shuffle method, shuffles the cards, but it shuffles a different deck and then throws it on the floor

Answer (score 2):

```
public void Shuffle()
{
    List<Kort> KortenÄrBlandade = new List<Kort>(...);
}
```

The Shuffle method uses a *local variable* that has the same name as Dealer.KortenÄrBlandade.  So after the method returns, you still have an empty list.  Fix:

```
public void Shuffle()
{
    Dealer.KortenÄrBlandade = new List<Kort>(...);
}
```

Do note that this is not a [proper shuffle](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html).  Class design is not correct either, either Shuffle() should be static or KortenÄrBlandade should not be static.  Confusion about the storage of variables is how you ended up writing this bug.